# Error 403 when trying to auth to YouTubeAPI v3 using oAuth

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, youtube-api

I'm working upon a react-native app which uses YouTube API v3, the issue which I meet is that the app throws me a 403 error message, when I try to authenticate using oAuth2. 
What I'm trying to do:

1. I make a GET request, where I send all the needed data for authentication : the `client_id`, `redirect_uri`, `response_type`, `scope`
2. The header used for this request is `'content-type': 'text/html'`
3. When I receive the response of the request, I open a `WebView` of this structure : `<WebView source={{ html: myResponse }} />`
4. This WebView shows me a google form, where I type my gmail login and password, next there should appear a window which should ask the permission of controlling my YouTube account,  but this image is met

[image: google log-in form]
[image: the error met after authorization]

I assume that the problem is in the WebView itself, and that I should use some adaptation of an in-app browser for React-Native, but before trying this I'd like to hear some solutions of yours, maybe they'll be more helpful than my idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [module](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin) for performing your signing in the app. It's a bit tricky to install, but it works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use a native web view to login with google.  You need to open it on the device browser.